# Do not understand the work of the regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"She's the one!".match(/['"](.+?)['"]/g);
```

Why is the result of Null? The idea is to be a coincidence "She'?

Comment: You do realize that the starting `"` and ending `"` are not actually part of the string? So the first quote it would match would be the one after She, and since there is no ending quote there is nothing else to match so you get null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches text between two quote mark or apostrophe characters. The string only has one in it. (The `"` that are used to delimit the string literal are not part of the data in the string).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match the outer quotes, which is unneeded

You can get your desired answer by using:

```
"She's the one!".match(/(.+?)['"]/g);
```